# How to group 2 by 2 style this plot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable, tikz-styles, grouping

I have the following plot that say something about performance:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend style={at={(.5,0.9)},anchor=north east},
symbolic x coords={Accuracy, score, recall, precision, hamming loss, jaccard similarity, F-beta score}, xtick=data,
x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east}]
\addlegendentry{data set 1}
\addplot[mark=*,thick,blue] coordinates {
(Accuracy,1.90129) (score,38.908839) (recall,50.29032309) (precision,28.09321093) (hamming loss,40.3093) (jaccard similarity,80.2323) (F-beta score,78.1920129)
};

\addlegendentry{data set 2}
\addplot[mark=diamond*,thick,red] coordinates {
(Accuracy,12.90129) (score,34.908839) (recall,60.29032309) (precision,22.09321093) (hamming loss,50.3093) (jaccard similarity,90.2323) (F-beta score,89.1920129)
};


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I plot 4 of these plots in one page as 2 by two style?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `groupplots` library of `pgfplots`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
group style={
group name=my plots,
group size=2 by 2,
xlabels at=edge bottom,
ylabels at=edge left,
horizontal sep=2cm,vertical sep=3cm,
},
legend style={at={(.5,0.9)},anchor=north east},
symbolic x coords={Accuracy, score, recall, precision, hamming loss, jaccard similarity, F-beta score}, xtick=data,
x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
width=0.5\linewidth
]
\nextgroupplot
\addlegendentry{data set 1}
\addplot[mark=*,thick,blue] coordinates {
(Accuracy,1.90129) (score,38.908839) (recall,50.29032309) (precision,28.09321093) (hamming loss,40.3093) (jaccard similarity,80.2323) (F-beta score,78.1920129)
};
\addlegendentry{data set 2}
\addplot[mark=diamond*,thick,red] coordinates {
(Accuracy,12.90129) (score,34.908839) (recall,60.29032309) (precision,22.09321093) (hamming loss,50.3093) (jaccard similarity,90.2323) (F-beta score,89.1920129)
};

\nextgroupplot
\addlegendentry{data set 1}
\addplot[mark=*,thick,blue] coordinates {
(Accuracy,1.90129) (score,38.908839) (recall,50.29032309) (precision,28.09321093) (hamming loss,40.3093) (jaccard similarity,80.2323) (F-beta score,78.1920129)
};
\addlegendentry{data set 2}
\addplot[mark=diamond*,thick,red] coordinates {
(Accuracy,12.90129) (score,34.908839) (recall,60.29032309) (precision,22.09321093) (hamming loss,50.3093) (jaccard similarity,90.2323) (F-beta score,89.1920129)
};

\nextgroupplot
\addlegendentry{data set 1}
\addplot[mark=*,thick,blue] coordinates {
(Accuracy,1.90129) (score,38.908839) (recall,50.29032309) (precision,28.09321093) (hamming loss,40.3093) (jaccard similarity,80.2323) (F-beta score,78.1920129)
};
\addlegendentry{data set 1}
\addplot[mark=*,thick,blue] coordinates {
(Accuracy,1.90129) (score,38.908839) (recall,50.29032309) (precision,28.09321093) (hamming loss,40.3093) (jaccard similarity,80.2323) (F-beta score,78.1920129)
};

\nextgroupplot
\addlegendentry{data set 1}
\addplot[mark=*,thick,blue] coordinates {
(Accuracy,1.90129) (score,38.908839) (recall,50.29032309) (precision,28.09321093) (hamming loss,40.3093) (jaccard similarity,80.2323) (F-beta score,78.1920129)
};
\addlegendentry{data set 2}
\addplot[mark=diamond*,thick,red] coordinates {
(Accuracy,12.90129) (score,34.908839) (recall,60.29032309) (precision,22.09321093) (hamming loss,50.3093) (jaccard similarity,90.2323) (F-beta score,89.1920129)
};


\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this series of question seem familiar to you at all...?

Comment: @cfr Series. I think I missed it. Where?

Comment: Just that this particular OP's questions seem very similar to the questions asked by certain previous OPs. But I likely just have a suspicious mind...

Comment: @cfr I don't think so. He uses same data and MWE but questions look different to me. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the remarks guys. Thanks @HarishKumar for helping me again. I really apreciate it, in fact I tried other aproaches from other questions on this community but I did not found something like this issue.